# Finite rotations with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, slanted

With my rudimentary knowledge of tikz I want to include to my classnotes that finite rotations are not commutative.This my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Initial position
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
%\node at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};

% Rotation autour de x
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!50,opacity=0.5] (-1,0,0.5) -- (-1,0,-0.5) -- (1,0,-0.5) -- (1,0,0.5) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,0,0.5) -- (1,0,-0.5);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0,-0.5) -- (1,0,0.5);
%\node[rotate=-45,yslant=1] at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};
\end{scope}

% Rotation autour de y
\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!70,opacity=0.5] (0.5,0,-1) -- (-0.5,0,-1) -- (-0.5,0,1) -- (0.5,0,1) -- cycle;
% Diagonales après rotation
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (0.5,0,1) -- (-0.5,0,-1);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-0.5,0,1) -- (0.5,0,-1);
%\node[rotate=45,xslant=-1] at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Initial position
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
%\node at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (0,-0.5,1) -- (0,-0.5,-1) -- (0,0.5,-1) -- (0,0.5,1) -- cycle;
% Diagonales après rotation
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (0,-0.5,-1) -- (0,0.5,1);
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (0,0.5,-1) -- (0,-0.5,1);
%\node[rotate=-90,yslant=1] at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (0,1,0.5) -- (0,1,-0.5) -- (0,-1,-0.5) -- (0,-1,0.5) -- cycle;
% Diagonales après rotation
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (0,-1,0.5) -- (0,1,-0.5);
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (0,-1,-0.5) -- (0,1,0.5);
%\node[rotate=-90,yslant=1] at (0,0,0) {\footnotesize Math};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, it takes a lot of manual work and the result could be more pleasant. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tikz-3dplot makes the rotations easier, with certain limitations.  The main coordinates correspond to lattitude and longitude for the POV, so the z axis is always up (or down).  The rotated coordinates rotate around the y or z axes easily, but to rotate around the x axis involves three rotations.

This is to demonstratw the rotations available, not the commutative properties.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0}% rotate around z axis
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{90}{0}% rotate around y axis
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{-90}% rotate rround x axis
\begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
\draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick, dashed,red] (-1,-0.5,0) -- (1,0.5,0);
\draw[thick, dashed,blue] (-1,0.5,0) -- (1,-0.5,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```